# Keep getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am working on javascript backbone project. I declared a global object like follow

```
window.App = { Vent: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events) }
```

I did above in `initialize` function like following

```
initialize: function () {
    window.App = { Vent: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events), hello: 'yes' };

    console.log(App); // This is ONE. see explanation below for ONE
    console.log(App.Vent); // This is TWO. see explanation below
}
```

**ONE**
This log line shows following

```
function (){return parent.apply(this,arguments)} app.js:22
```

**TWO**

This log line show

```
 undefined
```

Also if I do `console.log(App.hello)` it still says `undefined`

Please help me what am I doing wrong in this code?

**Update**

Here is all the related code to my problem. I am using requirejs and backbone

here is my main.js

```
require(['domReady', 'views/app', 'jqm'], function (domReady, AppView) {
    domReady(function () {
        window.App = { Vent: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events) };
        new AppView();
    });
});
```

here is `views/app.js` file

```
define(['backbone', 'views/home/homes', 'collections/homes'], function (Backbone, HomesView, HomesCollection ) {
    var App = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'div#page',

        events: {
            'swipeleft': 'nextView',
            'swiperight': 'preView'
        },

        nextView: function (e) {
            console.log(App.Vent);
            //App.Vent.trigger('changeView', { direction: 'next' });
        },

        preView: function (e) {
            console.log(App.Vent);
            //App.Vent.trigger('changeView', { direction: 'prev' });
        }
    });

    return App;
});
```

What I am doing in this file is when user `swipes left or right` then it calls nextView and preView functions. In these functions I want to trigger and Event which I listen to them in another view. But right now I want to console it. But it says `undefined`

Comment: You probably have a `var App` between the `initialize` function (inclusive) and the global scope (exclusive) which shadows the global scope's `App`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté could you please elaborate a little more

Comment: It works correct. `console.log(App);` `->` `Object {Vent: Object}`

Comment: Do a ctrl+f on the source file for `var App` and post the related code if it finds any match. What I meant is described as [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I do not have any var app in the source.

Comment: @NOX no it does not show `Object {Vent: Object}`. Please see my code above what it shows.

Comment: If you do this in a fiddle or any other environment, it will show Object as NOX mentioned. You probably have an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Do I post all the related code?

Comment: Well, at least enough to reproduce the issue. You can fiddle around [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jBCCq/).

Comment: Try to change `var App = Backbone.View.extend({` to something else. Like this: `var iApp = Backbone.View.extend({`.

Comment: @NOX now when I changed `App` to `iApp` it works. Thank you :).

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
```

to something else. Like this:

```
var iApp = Backbone.View.extend({
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why it is working using iApp but not on App?

Comment: When you do `var App = Backbone.View.extend({});`, you overwrite your old `App` variable. `var a = 2; var a = 3;`, you can access `2` anymore.